# Arcmap Maplex labeling engine bug workaround - labeling expressions won't recognize multiple spaces

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, labeling, maplex

I am labeling points in ArcMap using the Maplex labeling engine using a short Python script. The labels are rotated depending on an 'angle' field.

```
def FindLabel ( [name], [city], [num] ):
  Buffer = "\n" + " "
  if ([city] and [num] and [name]):
     return [name] + "\n" + [city] + "\n" +  [num].replace("+", "\n")
  elif ([num] and [name]):
     return [name] + "\n" + [num].replace("+", "\n")
  elif ([city] and [name]):
     return [name] + "\n" + [num].replace("+", "\n")
  elif [name]:
     return [name] + Buffer
```

Labels with one line appear to have an offset (about -4 y) from the end of the point's symbol, but labels with multiple lines appear centered. I wanted to add empty lines to my labeling script so that it would appear centered, but they appear to have no effect. This article notes the bug, but provides no workaround: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30655

Does anyone have any suggestions to center labels with one line of text?

Edit:
I didn't realize this option was enabled. If anyone else has this problem, make sure you are aware of this option.

[image: Maplex options]

Comment: Have you tried a line with a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) so it just _looks_ empty?

Comment: use commas to stack  S = S.replace(', ', '\n') http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000027000000

Comment: Erica: The non-breaking space seems to work. Do you know if there is a difference between (    &nbsp;) and (    u"\u00A0")?
Mapperz: my issue is that I need to add empty lines to a stack so that a line will appear centered. It stacks fine when there are multiple lines, but is offset when there is just one line (I'm not sure why).

Comment: The above bug is in following version of arcgis Software:  ArcGIS - ArcEditor 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3.1, 10 ArcGIS - ArcInfo 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3.1, 10 ArcGIS - ArcView 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.3.1, 10--------Your question tag is Arcgis 10.2

Comment: @msi_g: I am encountering the same bug in 10.2 and have reported it to Esri.

Comment: @juturna One is HTML and one is Unicode, but both are non-breaking spaces. There may be situations in which one or the other isn't properly interpreted by ArcMap; however, I don't know enough about the situation to give you a good answer there. The `&nbsp;` was honestly a lucky guess :)

Comment: if i got you, you need newline only. Have u used VBScript or JScript?

Comment: @msi_g Newlines seem to be only honored if there is something in the new line. Erica's recommendation of using a non-breaking space works in conjunction with a newline.I haven't tried this with VBScript of JScript; Python is a requirement for me in this case.

Comment: @juturna  for me(Arc map 10.1 sp1) there is no problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/fg10reczyitq4bv/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: @msi_g Interesting. Can you recreate it with rotation based on an 'angle' field?

Comment: @juturna I have no problem even in case of rotation and NULL case    https://www.dropbox.com/s/fg10reczyitq4bv/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: @msi_g There must be something else wrong on my end then. I will post an update if I discover what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maplex can do some neat things, but it does have some odd quirks. I've [logged a few Maplex bugs](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDkwMjk2) myself.

If that spacing is driving you crazy, you can try to set up individual label classes or even individual layers for each of your four if statements:

[image: Layer Properties]

This should allow you more flexibility when setting up your labels for better placement.